# Как отправить raw binary на ip адрес

Tags: c#, request, binary

[image: через Putty подключаюсь к ip через raw]

[image: Потом текстом пишу команду и приходит ответ ОК]

Вопрос в том как реализовать данное решение на языке C#

```
public void Send(byte[] rawData, IPEndPoint target)
    {
        // change what you pass to this constructor to your needs
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IPv4);

        try
        {
            s.Connect(target);
            s.Send(rawData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            // handle this exception
        }
    }
```

попробовал так но в ответ ошибка
спасибо за помощь)

Comment: `ошибка спасибо за помощь` - любопытная ошибка. Ну а если серьезно, то раз говорите об ошибке, то укажите ее!

Comment: выходила ошибка протокола но потом поменял SocketType.Raw и теперь вроде как ошибки нету, но не понятно как получить результат ответа, попробовал преобразовать s.Send(rawData).toString(); и в ответ 10 приходит

Comment: спасибо, отправлять научился, теперь понять бы как получить ответ?

Comment: Int32 bytes = s.Receive(RecvBytes, RecvBytes.Length, 0);
                result += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RecvBytes, 0, bytes);

                while (bytes > 0)
                {
                    bytes = s.Receive(RecvBytes, RecvBytes.Length, 0);
                    result += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RecvBytes, 0, bytes);
                }

Comment: попробовал получить данные из примера который вы скинули, команда отправляется но потом программа просто зависает

Comment: спасибо большое разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Из примера Socket Constructors (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket__ctor_System_Net_Sockets_AddressFamily_System_Net_Sockets_SocketType_System_Net_Sockets_ProtocolType_):

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

`ProtocolType` должен быть `Tcp`. PUTTY raw format означает TCP (то есть, raw TCP, а не SSH, Serial итд.)

Перед выходом из функции нужно принять ответ.